# No Cakephp, por que o método input gera uma um seletor vazio?

Tags: php, cakephp, formview

Em minha aplicação encontra-se 2 modelos relacionados e Shortcut e Role, onde Role possui vários Shortcuts, o ligação entre os dois ocorre normalmente, com exceção ao tentar criar um input na view "save" do controller Shortcut para selecionar um Role existente.

Model Shortcut

```
<?php
class Shortcut extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'Shortcut';
public $diplayField = 'title';  
public $useTable = 'shortcuts';
public $belongsTo = array( 'Role' => array('className' => 'Role','foreignKey' =>          'role_id' ) );
}

?>
```

Model Role

```
class Role extends AppModel
{
public $name ='Role';
public $useTable = 'roles';
public $displayField = 'title';

public function getAdminRole()
{
    return 3;
}
public function getUserRole()
{
    return 2;
}
public function getPublicRole()
{
    return 1;
}
}
```

View/Shortcuts/Save

```
<?php echo $this -> Form -> create('Shortcut'); ?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>TÍTULO</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this -> Form -> input('title',array('label'=>null));?>
    </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>LINK</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this -> Form -> input('link',array('label'=>null));?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>PERMISSÃO</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this -> Form -> input('role_id',array('label'=>null));?    >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this -> Form ->      submit('Enviar',array('controller'=>'shortcuts','action'=>'save'));?>
    </td>
</tr>   
</table>
<?php echo $this ->  Form -> end();?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem uma convenção: se existir na view uma variável com o nome plural do model relacionado, ele preenche as opções do dropdown sozinho. Por exemplo, coloque isso no controller, em `Shortcuts::save`:

```
$this->set('roles', $this->Shortcut->Role->find('list'));
```

Também é possível forçar a lista de opções passando uma array na chave `'options'`:

```
echo $this->Form->input('role_id', array(
    'label' => null,
    'options' => array(
        1 => 'Public',
        2 => 'User',
        3 => 'Admin'
    )
));
```

Comment: então, mas em um projeto anterior eu apenas fiz o input com o campo que faz referencia á outra tabela, e ja era incluído na caixa de opções, todos os registros daquela tabela

Comment: Achei um negócio que eu não sabia no [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html), e editei a resposta. Veja se assim resolve.